Sum up query in Laravel

$users = User::select('id', 'name','code')
    ->with(['todaysAssignedRoutePlans' => function ($q) use ($outletIds) {
        $q->select('id', 'name', 'territory_id', 'assigned_to')
            ->with(['territory' => function ($q) use ($outletIds) {
                $q->withCount(['outlets as distinct_outlets' => function ($q) use ($outletIds) {
                    $q->whereIn('id', $outletIds)->distinct();
                }]);
            }]);
    }])
    ->withCount(['todaysAssignedRoutePlans as total_route'])
    ->get();

In my application, I have some models and the relationship is

User has Many todaysAssignedRoutePlans.
todaysAssignedRoutePlans belong to a territory
The territory has many outlets.

I want to retrieve each user with the number of todaysAssignedRoutePlans and the number of outlets.
So far, I am getting todaysAssignedRoutePlans number, but can't sum up all outlets for distinct territories for each User...
My code gives outlet count on territorywise. But I want to sum up it userwise...
Relationship is like.

I want to find out. User:total_route,total_outlet
Your help is highly appreciated.

Please don't post images of code or errors!

can you post what you get vs what you want? I'm not sure where you are stuck

@krisgjika I am getting something like [ "id" => 3 "name" => "MD. SAFIQUE" "total_route" => 15 todays_assigned_route_plans[ "id" => 1 "name" => "LA" territory[ "id"=>2 distinct_outlet = 30] ...and for another todays_assigned_route_plans its territory have 40 distinct outlets...similarly, 15 territories have a different number of distinct outlet, a same territory can come twice...I want to Sum up the number of outlets for distinct territories for each user...I want something.  [ "id" => 3 "name" => "MD. SAFIQUE" "total_route" => 15 "total_outlet" = 60

This is how I would go about defining the models:
User Model
public function today_assigned_route_plans() {
   return $this->hasMany(todaysAssignedRoutePlans::class);
}

todaysAssignedRoutePlans Model
public function territory() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Territory::class);
}

territory model
public function outlets() {
   return $this->hasMany(Outlet::class);
}

With these relationships defined, in your Controller, or wherever you are calling the user from, all you have to do is use the definitions.

$users = User::with('today_assigned_route_plans', 'today_assigned_route_plans.territory', 'today_assigned_route_plans.territory.outlets')->get() 


I have all the relations as you have said. However, I don't know why withCount is not working for nested relations or if should it work.  I need a total of 'today_assigned_route_plans' and a total of outlets for each user. since multiple today_assigned_route_plans can have the same territory, I need to check if the outlets are not being counted twice also.....

So, until $users = User::with('todaysAssignedRoutePlans', 'todaysAssignedRoutePlans.territory', 'todaysAssignedRoutePlans.territory.outlets')
->withCount('todaysAssignedRoutePlans')
->get();  works fine.. But when I try  -
$users = User::with('todaysAssignedRoutePlans', 'todaysAssignedRoutePlans.territory', 'todaysAssignedRoutePlans.territory.outlets')
->withCount('todaysAssignedRoutePlans.territory.outlets')
->get();  It gives me an error. Call to undefined method App\Models\Acl\User::todaysAssignedRoutePlans.territory()

Btw... have you thought of using resources?
php artisan make:resource UserResource

No, I am using raw query instead to get the desired result... And withCount is only works if the relation is declared in the model directly. anyway, thank you for your time..
